# Consumer thread state when no messages are available in the given queue in rabbitmq

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

I am just curious about the consumer state when no data is published to queue where the consumer is linked

```
@Component
public class ABC {

@RabbitListener(queues = RabbitQueueName,containerFactory = RABBIT_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY, id =SomeId)
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        try {
            //business logic
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //some logger
        }
    }
}
```

Any link which explains this is more useful
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the container type.

With the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` (default), the amqp-client pushes new deliveries into a `BlockingQueue`; the listener thread polls that queue for new messages according to the `receiveTimeout` (default 1 second). If you turn on TRACE logging, you will see that polling.

With the `DirectMessageListenerContainer`, the listener is called directly by the amqp-client thread whenever a new message arrives.

Comment: didn't get it clearly can you please elaborate by taking an example

Comment: I don't think I can say any more to make it clearer; exactly what don't you understand?

Comment: i didn't get about this BlockingQueue and listener thread polls

Comment: See here https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#choose-container it explains a little bit about the internals and why the blocking queue was needed (with earlier amqp-client versions).

Answer (score 0):

See `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`:

```
/**
 * An event that is emitted when a container is idle if the container
 * is configured to do so.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 1.6
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ListenerContainerIdleEvent extends AmqpEvent {
```

Docs are here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers